# Spring Boot JPA - SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm Trying to save the value using jpa. I Got **SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.**

[image: Database ER Diagram]

**My Model Class - (user_answers) Table:**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answers")
data class CustomUserAnswer (
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @Column(name="answer")
    var answer: String = "",
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "user_answer_id")
    var userAnswerId: UUID,
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    var questionId: UUID):Serializable{}
```

**My Model Class - (user_answer_relt)**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answer_relt")
data class UserAnswerRelt(
        @Id
        @Type(type = "uuid-char")
        @Column(name = "id")
        var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
        @Column(name="answer_submitted_by")
        var submittedUserName : String = "",
        @Type(type = "uuid-char")
        @Column(name="user_id")
        var userId : UUID
) {}
```

First I'm Save User_Answer_Relt Values and Get User_Answer_Id Then I Build User_Answer class with User_Answer_Id

So, Now I'm Trying to save the User_Answer Value That time I'm Getting the Below Issue.

**Error :**

```
> 19:49:43.079 [http-nio-9010-exec-1] ERROR
> o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot add or update a child row:
> a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`user_answers`, CONSTRAINT
> `user_question_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES
> `questions` (`id`)) 19:49:43.129 [http-nio-9010-exec-1] ERROR
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet
> [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
> execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
> execute statement] with root cause
> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`test`.`user_answers`, CONSTRAINT `user_question_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY
> (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`))
```

**I know If The Question_Id is not available in the question table means it's throw the above exception but I double checked the data it's correct. but i don't know the exact reason.**

**I Also Tried the Join Column  In the Model,But  i Still got the same issue**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answers")
data class UserAnswer(
        @Id
        @Type(type = "uuid-char")
        @Column(name = "id")
        var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
        @Column(name="answer")
        var answer: String = "",
        @Type(type = "uuid-char")
        @Column(name = "user_answer_id")
        var userAnswerId: UUID,
        @Column(name = "question_id")
        var questionId:UUID,
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
        @JoinColumn(name = "question_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
        var question: Question?

){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the actual issue.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answers")
data class CustomUserAnswer (
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @Column(name="answer")
    var answer: String = "",
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "user_answer_id")
    var userAnswerId: UUID,
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    var questionId: UUID):Serializable{}
```

In the above code, I forgot to add Column internal type I made a fix by adding the following code.

```
     @Type(type = "uuid-char")
     @Column(name = "question_id")
     var questionId: UUID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entities are not reflecting the relationships between each other.

Hibernate will flush the changes in an order that does not necessarily reflect the order of your code, but if it knows how things are related it can send changes in a safe order.

CustomerUserAnswer should have properties of type UserAnswerRelt and Question rather than UUID and you will need @JoinColumn annotations.

Comment: i updated the Question Description please check, thank  you.

Comment: If you are attaching an answer to an existing question, retrieve that question entity from the DB and associate it with the answer entity that you are creating

Comment: So, What i need to change in the code. Please help i'll understand

Comment: Use JoinColumn on the answerrelt too, use a JPA repository to retrieve question by ID, and create an object graph with combination of question, answer and answerrelt, hibernate will persist your object graph correctly.

Comment: Hi, not sure if that helped or not, but with Spring Boot it is really easy, just remember that for this to work you just have to have entities that reflect the data and relationships in your database, either retrieved from the database via a repository if they already exist, or created in memory if they are going to be new rows in the DB.

Comment: thanks for your help. i finally fix my issue. i updated in the answer part.

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like the question just couldn't be found because the generated SQL was specifying the UUID in the wrong format. Glad you got to the bottom of that. On reflection then, would it be better to use a different data type in the DB - first to ensure indexes are compact, and also it would have given a more meaningful error here if you had tried to insert the wrong type.